# Wine Version 3.0.3 bug

Tags: debian, kali-linux, wine

I have a slight issue with Wine right now which is kinda annoying. Running on:

> Linux 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Wine works just fine except every time I run a wine command, before it executes I get this timed out warning / error / bug

```
000f:err:service:process_send_command receiving command result timed out
```

And then it proceeds to run properly. I tried to Google the error message but couldn't find out how to fix it. Does anybody else have this issue? How can I fix it?

I'm running Wine version:

> wine-3.0.3 (Debian 3.0.3-2)

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be trying  to run Wine on Kali.

Comment: @Scott: Wine is required for certain attacks like EternalBlue, so not having it on Kali is not an option these days. Don't know what version of Wine you're using, but you could try re-installing it or updating it to see if that was a bug with the version of wine you have.

Comment: Never did figure this out. Don't have the problem anymore after re-installing the latest version of kali months later. Also Thanks @Will for the educational response. Wine is essential for numerous applications in kali linux. Not sure why people thought Scott's comment was useful.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this exact error in Kali linux(Linux kali 4.17.0-kali1-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.8-1kali1 (2018-07-24) i686 GNU/Linux) I reinstalled Wine :)

```
apt purge wine

apt install wine
```

I hope this will help.